# C# + PHP Error at receiving a message

Tags: c#, php

So i made it that my php website connects to my C# Server,
But whenever i refresh my webpage, the program closes down with an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
>   occurred in System.dll

Error comes up here:

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
    int received;

    try
    {
        received = current.EndReceive(AR);
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
        current.Close(); // Dont shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway
        _clientSockets.Remove(current);
        return;
    }

    byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
    Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuf, received);
    string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
    Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);

    if (text.ToLower() == "get time") // Client requested time
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text is a get time request");
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        current.Send(data);
        Console.WriteLine("Time sent to client");
    }
    else if (text.ToLower() == "exit") // Client wants to exit gracefully
    {
        // Always Shutdown before closing
        current.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        current.Close();
        _clientSockets.Remove(current);
        Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text is an invalid request");
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Invalid request");
        current.Send(data);
        Console.WriteLine("Warning Sent");
    }

    current.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
}
```

And to be sure this line:

```
current.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
```

**EDIT:** The catch returned:

> 10053 => Software caused connection abort. An established connection
>   was aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a
>   data transmission time-out or protocol error.

so i think its the PHP that is doing the data transmission wrong:

```
<?PHP

require_once('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$porn = "Test";
$user = $_POST['user'];
$username = $user;
$ulen = strlen($username);
//socket_send($socket, $username, $ulen, 0);
socket_write($socket, $username);
$read = socket_read($socket,2048) or die("Cannot read from socket");

}else{
  echo "Not loaded";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="status">
    <?php echo $read; ?>
  </div>
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Load">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Connection.php:

```
<?php
    $service_port = 100;
    $address = '127.0.0.1';
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port)or die("Cannot connect");
    socket_set_nonblock($socket);
?>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should catch the exception, and look at the message and the [SocketException.ErrorCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.errorcode(v=vs.110).aspx) property - there you will find the internal error code. Then look at the [WinSock2 error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) and find the error code, it will most likely tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Im getting from the catch only : The software on ur hostcomputer has terminated an connection < Sorry i translated it from my language. Im not getting the SocketException.ErrorCode property

Comment: The socketexception throwed this: Software caused connection abort.
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a data transmission time-out or protocol error.